# Android: Custom dialog view, change button color before showing for first time

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-custom-view, android-dialogfragment

I'm making something like a social app.

I would like that if someone has already viewed something before, that the button in the view will change colors.

I have a method to check if someone has viewed this list before. It works in the clickListener, and will say "Already pressed."

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to change the color of the button, maybe on the onCreate method. I've tried passing it as an argument, but the color will change on the second time the list is pulled up...

This is how I call up my dialog and pass it the list ID.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View r = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_dialog_layout, container, false);

    checklistView = (UserlistView) r.findViewById(R.id.user_list);
    checklistview.getList(getArguments().getString("list_id")); // Can be modified

    return r;
}
```

in that function getList, I make my call to my database to get the info of the list.

```
public void getList(final String listID) {
    // TODO fetch list information from params and fill fields
    Event.requestEvent(listID, "AuthToken", new List.ListReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onListReceived(lissts... lissteses) {
            List lst = lissteses[0];
            setInfo(lst);
            LISTID = listID;


        }
    });
}

public void setInfo(List lst){


    listTitleView.setText(lst.listName);
    viewsCount.setText(Integer.toString(lst.views));

}
```

I have a checker function to see if the user has already clicked the "have viewed"

public static boolean viewed(String id, final String user){
        DatabaseReference rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("views").child(id);

```
    rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user)){
                result = true;
            }
            else{
                result = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

then, I wanted to call it in the getList() as such

```
if(viewed(lstID, curuser){
     viewButton.setColorFilter(R.color.blue);
 }
```

this doesn't work for the first time the view is created, and so, if the user has already clicked view, logs out and logs back in, and click view again, messing up the view count.

Comment: You should show us the code you use to handle the color changing and where you put them then we can help you. Did you set the onClickListener after the view is updated?

Comment: plz update your code here, so I can here...

Comment: Post your code here, So that we can figure out issue

Comment: I edit the question to include code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int flag=0;
    button.setOnClickLitener(new OnClickListener()){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            flag++;

        }
    });
if(flag>0){
 button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this.

```
button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.youCustomColor));
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem I'm having is doing it before the first time the view is pulled up.

Comment: Share your code where you find button is already pressed or not.